# Simplifying a Geometric Series with Two Power Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> I have derived a geometric series below that I want to simplify but keep making a mess. Can anyone help?
>   $$s = aq^{n-1}r^{0} + aq^{n-2}r^{1} + \dotsb + aq^{1}r^{n-2} + aq^{0}r^{n-1}$$

I get the following, but I know it's wrong

$$s = \frac{aq^{n-1} - (ar^{n})/q}{1 - (r/q)}$$

Comment: Very happy with the answer and hints below. I'm left wondering why my approach of trying to find rs/q like shown on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series didn't work but that's another question I guess ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align}
S & = aq^{n-1}r^{0} + aq^{n-2}r^{1} + \cdots + aq^{1}r^{n-2} + aq^{0}r^{n-1}\\
& = aq^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{r}{q}+ \cdots  +\frac{r^{n-1}}{q^{n-1}}\right)\\
& = aq^{n-1} \frac{1-\frac{r^n}{q^n}}{1-\frac{r}{q}} \\
& = a\frac{q^n-r^n}{q-r}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that we have

$$A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\ldots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1})$$

and therefore

$$A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+\ldots+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1}=\frac{A^n-B^n}{A-B}=A^{n-1}\frac{1-\left(\frac B A\right)^n}{1-\frac B A}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the high-school formula:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}). $$

Comment: This got me there myself before @Math Lover thanks. Upvoted but I have no reputation here ..

Answer (score 0):

To find the common ratio (and prove that it is common, and hence a geometric series), divide two successive terms:
$$\frac{aq^{n-1-(k+1)}r^{k+1}}{aq^{n-1-k}r^k} = \frac{r}{q}.$$
Note that this doesn't depend on $n$, so the ratio is common between all terms. The initial term is $aq^{n-1}$, and there are $n$ terms, so the sum is,
$$s = aq^{n-1} \frac{\left(\frac{r}{q}\right)^n - 1}{\frac{r}{q} - 1} = aq\frac{qr^n - 1}{r - q}$$